# how many blocks will be in hdfs for 5 files of 150 mb each

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

suppose there are 5 file of 150 mb each. Now when I put these files in hdfs(where block size is 64 mb) then how many number of blocks will be per file and total blocks. 
Also how many number of splits will be for all files. and how many number of mappers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There will be `3 blocks` per file ( 64mb,64mb,32mb). So total No. of blocks `5*3 = 15`

So the No. of splits will be 15. So the No of mapper(if using `FileInputFormat`) = 15.

Explanation:

> HDFS do not take an entire block to store a file with size < block
>   size. We can consider an example, Assume HDFS block size = 64MB. We
>   have some files to store having size =10MB, then the name node will
>   do: ·         Search for an available block
>
> ·         Client will write date into it
>
> ·         After writer is closed, it is considered that file is closed
>   for writing. i.e, file is created with size 10MB
>
> ·         Then there is 53MB available in that block. This will be
>   freed up and added to available space.
>
> ·         Thus the block for this file only occupy 10MB  (block resize
>   will happen)

Comment: I can improve this answer by posting a link to the [official documentation](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/FAQ#If_a_block_size_of_64MB_is_used_and_a_file_is_written_that_uses_less_than_64MB.2C_will_64MB_of_disk_space_be_consumed.3F)

Answer (score 1):

Your files are  stored in hdfs.

```
1file =100mb
block size=64mb
```

so `1 file split in 2 block`.

you have 5files

```
5*2=10blocks.
```

1 mapper per split so

```
 10blocks=10mapper
```

please confirm, in your question headline files size is 150mb but in question is 100mb.
it will same divide as per above.

Comment: you mean for 100mb per file there will one block of 64mb and one of 36 mb? actually I was confused with that will it append the other file data in the same block of first file which contains 36 mb data

Comment: it will not append, will create new block.see this blog--http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/02/the-small-files-problem/